# Calling javascript function from external xslt file that is included in a main xslt file

Tags: xslt

I need help please.
I have javascript defined in an XSLT file called `file_a.xsl`.
I have also a second XSLT file called `file_b.xslt`.
I have been struggling to call the `sayHello()` function defined in `file_a.xsl` from `file_b.xsl`.

Her is `file_a.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:foo="http://www.cateringportal.com/"
                   extension-element-prefixes="msxsl">



<msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="foo">
        <![CDATA[
        function sayHello()  
        {  
                return "hello there";  
        }  
        ]]>
      </msxsl:script>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Her is `file_b.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:foo="http://www.cateringportal.com/" >
  <xsl:include href="helloXSL.xsl" />

<xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <br/>


<xsl:value-of select="foo:sayHello()”/> 

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I will be happy for a help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I would use better `xsl:import` than `xsl:include`, your trasnforms are correct and perfectly working. I tested it with **MSXSL 4.0**, perhaps you are using an obsolete version.

The result is:

```
 <br xmlns:foo="http://www.cateringportal.com/">hello there
```

What's the problem there?

Answer (score 0):

I fell over this - I think this is what you need ...
As it shows xmlns:cosSin is the namespace
the select statement calls the function using cosSin: prefix

Works in MS version 4 also ....

...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:cosSin="urn:cosSin">
...
 <text fill="white" stroke="none" font-size="48" text-anchor="middle">       
       <xsl:attribute name="x"><xsl:value-of select="(cosSin:returnX($offSet + ($slicePercentage div 2)) * 600) + 1000" /></xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="y"><xsl:value-of select="(cosSin:returnY($offSet + ($slicePercentage div 2)) * 600) + 1000" /></xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:value-of select="$slicePercentage" /> %
     </text>
  ...
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="cosSin">
function returnX(percent) {
  var degree = percent * 3.6;
  return Math.cos(degree*Math.PI/180);
}
function returnY(percent) {
  var degree = percent * 3.6;
  return Math.sin(degree*Math.PI/180);
}
</msxsl:script>
```